# regex if then pattern match

Tags: regex, looker-studio

I have a page title string that I want to grab a substring (the Brand Name) from, however it doesn't appear in the same spot all the time.

Page Title:

- Brand Name A | Book now
- Brand Name B | Order here
- Content | Brand Name A | Order now
- Content | Brand Name 7 | Click here

Desired output:

- Brand Name A
- Brand Name B
- Brand Name A
- Brand Name 7

I  can get the Brand Name from the first two using
`(^[^|]+)`  and grab  the Brand  Name from the second two with `\|(.*).*(?=\|)` - although it grabs the | as well.

However, I need the first regex to apply when there is 1 pipe and the second regex to apply when there  are 2 pipes. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `REGEXP_EXTRACT` we can try:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT("Content | Brand Name A | Order now", "\\s*([^|]+?)\\s+\\|[^|]+$")
```

Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cFbvE5/2).